# Cant display file icon in jtable

Tags: java, jtable

I am having trouble displaying the file thumbnail in my JTable.
instead of icon it is showing text/file type.
here is my code:

```
icon = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(content[i]);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5CbJ.png)

Comment: how are you doing to display the icon? How is the Cell Renderer implemented?

Comment: my table has an object data from a directory that i choose and i want it to show the icon of the file in column 1 like in the pic that i uploaded but the result is a text not an image... and i am using a GUI builder in netbeans...

Comment: Check you implementation of `getColumnClass()`. If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.